# change mongo admin password on an arbiter

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I have a mongoDB replicaSet that has 3 DBs - PRIMARY/SECONDARY + Arbiter.
All 3 were installed the same manner - meaning they have admin database with a default password.

Now - I want to change the default passwords. On primary/secondary it worked well.

```
mongo admin -u admin -p <password> --authenticationDatabase=admin
db.changeUserPassword("admin",<new password>)
```

However - in the arbiter it isn't working (even after adding `rs.slaveOK()` in the PRIMARY)

I'm getting:

```
2016-12-01T00:18:51.408-0800 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Updating user failed: not master :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.updateUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1319:15
DB.prototype.changeUserPassword@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1323:9
@(shell):1:1
```

Any ideas how to change arbiter admin password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got your replicaset setup correctly the users will get propagated to the rest of the cluster after creating/updating the user on the primary node.

You can check this by logging on to one of the secondaries and doing

```
>use admin
>db.system.users.find();
```

As for the arbiter it shouldn't be storing any data, hence it has no admin database to store users:

```
rs01:ARBITER> rs.slaveOk()
rs01:ARBITER> use admin
switched to db admin
rs01:ARBITER> show collections
rs01:ARBITER>
```

Comment: Well - Since the "app" (our installer) installed this mahcine just like the others - it contains an admin database: use admin -> show collections -> system.users
system.version

Comment: I'm thinking I should remove admin collection in the arbiter and let it propogate... will try and update...

Comment: Eventually couldn't remove collection - and just deleted the DB of the arbiter (which is the most correct thing to do)